# switching between 2 views

Tags: views

I have created two Views, I then placed the second view on the footer of the first view. Main view has date, an image, attachment and size of the attachment, the second one has an images that are linked to a files. 
Output, latest one should always display on the top with an image, attachment and size of the attachment which I got it right when I click on the image from the footer I want an image to display above with the attached file and the size. May anyone help on how I can do the switching part in. See an the attached, am using Drupal 7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have actually resolved my problem by adding a piece of php code within filter criteria. see attached.

[image: Solution to my problem]